# Agda on Windows, incomplete installation?

Tags: agda

I've just installed Agda v. 2.4.2.2 from the prebuilt Windows package.
Everything seems to be in place, however, for even the simple module declaration like

```
module X1  where
```

compilation returns the following error:

```
The name of the top level module does not match the file name. The
module X1 should be defined in one of the following files:
  C:\agda-stdlib-0.13\src\X1.agda
  C:\agda-stdlib-0.13\src\X1.lagda
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell\i386-windows-ghc-7.8.3\Agda-2.4.2.2\lib\prim\X1.agda
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell\i386-windows-ghc-7.8.3\Agda-2.4.2.2\lib\prim\X1.lagda
```

The filename is X1.agda.

Addition:

I've added the source folder to the Agda include directories and that seems to have solved the above issue. Then, following a tutorial, I extended my source with a main function.

```
module x where

  open System.IO

  main : IO Unit
  main = putStrLn "Hello world!"
```

Now I get this message:

```
The IO action 'main' is not defined in module `MAlonzo.Code.Qx'
```

Any help would be appreciated.